# "undefined reference to" linking on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linker

I'm relatively new to C & C++ and stuck at compiling (or should I say linking) for the whole 2 days. Anyone gives me an idea would be appreciated.
Error message and 3 code files are below. These are what I cut down to minimum from I'm actually working on so that you guys can take a better glimpse at.

Env: Ubuntu 10.10, Eclipse Indigo CDT, g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5

Error message:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project SceneRec2 ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/AdaBoost.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I"/home/ubuntuLove/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SceneRec2/Includes" -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-30/arch/um/include/shared -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/AdaBoost.d" -MT"src/AdaBoost.d" -o "src/AdaBoost.o" "../src/AdaBoost.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/AdaBoost.cpp

Building file: ../src/AdaMain.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I"/home/ubuntuLove/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SceneRec2/Includes" -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-30/arch/um/include/shared -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/AdaMain.d" -MT"src/AdaMain.d" -o "src/AdaMain.o" "../src/AdaMain.cpp"
../src/AdaMain.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
../src/AdaMain.cpp:6: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
Finished building: ../src/AdaMain.cpp

Building target: SceneRec2
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "SceneRec2"  ./src/AdaBoost.o ./src/AdaMain.o   
./src/AdaMain.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntuLove/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SceneRec2/Debug/../src/AdaMain.cpp:5: undefined reference to `AdaBoost<double>::AdaBoost()'
/home/ubuntuLove/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SceneRec2/Debug/../src/AdaMain.cpp:6: undefined reference to `AdaBoost<double>::readFromFile(char*)'
/home/ubuntuLove/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SceneRec2/Debug/../src/AdaMain.cpp:8: undefined reference to `AdaBoost<double>::~AdaBoost()'
/home/ubuntuLove/Documents/workspace_eclipse/SceneRec2/Debug/../src/AdaMain.cpp:8: undefined reference to `AdaBoost<double>::~AdaBoost()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SceneRec2] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Note-1. I receive the same result when I execute g++ on terminal.

Note-2. The path of .o files in the argument for linker should be correct (./src/###.o).

AdaBoost.h

```
#ifndef _ADABOOST_H
#define _ADABOOST_H

#include <iostream>

const double eps = 2.2204e-16;

template<class T>
class AdaBoost
{
        int N; //Number of Instances
        int D; //Number of Dimensions
        int nL; //Number of Learners / Classifiers / Rules

        T** fVectors;
        int* labels;

        void learnRule(int t, double* dist);
        double genRule(int t, int* L, double* dist);

    public:

        //Default Constructor
        AdaBoost();

        //Constructor
        AdaBoost(T** data, int* labels, int n, int d, int nL);

        //Train function
        void train();

        //Test function
        void test(double** data, double* pMap);
        void test(double** data, double* pMap, int n);

        int writeToFile(char* fName);
        int readFromFile(char* fName);

        //Destructor
        ~AdaBoost();
};
#endif
```

AdaBoost.cpp

```
#include "AdaBoost.h"    
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template class AdaBoost<double> ;

template<class T>
int AdaBoost<T>::readFromFile(char* fName) {

    ifstream inFile;

    int temp;
    int d, dir;
    float thr, wt;

    inFile.open(fName);
    if (!inFile)
        return 0;

    inFile >> temp;
    this->nL = temp;

    int k = 0;
    while (!inFile.eof() && k < nL) {

        inFile >> d;
        inFile >> thr;
        inFile >> dir;
        inFile >> wt;

        k++;
    }

    inFile.close();

    return 1;
}
```

AdaMain.cpp

```
#include "AdaBoost.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AdaBoost<double> rdClass;
    rdClass.readFromFile("Naerer");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the definition of `template<class T>
int AdaBoost<T>::readFromFile(char* fName)` into `AdaBoost.h`, and remove `AdaBoost.cpp` from your build.

It's best to put all template code into the header.  C++ linkers are required to eliminate duplicate instantiations of template code so you won't get "multiply defined symbol" errors.

P.S. You should declare the function as `template<class T>
int AdaBoost<T>::readFromFile(const char* fName)` to get rid of the `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’` warning. The function does not need to alter the filename.

Comment: You don't need to put everything in the header if you use explicit instantiation.

Comment: I'm the original questioner and this works out after playing around with other suggestions together. Thank you!

Comment: @Georg: No, you don't have to, but explicit instantiation is a really complex thing to force on a new programmer. Best to hold off on that until it's actually needed.

Comment: Well, he already used it in the code posted (knowingly or not, no way to know upfront).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using explicit instantiation, you have to define the generic version of the member function before instantiating the class:

```
template<class T>
int AdaBoost<T>::readFromFile(char* fName) {
    // ...
}

template class AdaBoost<double>;
```

However, if you don't have a specific or pressing reason to use explicit instantiation in the first place, go with the other recommendations and define the templates in the header.

Comment: Thank you. This time I worked around by other approach (moving declarations that concern template to header file), but I'll keep it mind your opinion too (it's just I don't fully understand when I want to use explicit instantiating yet).

Comment: @user: It's very rare that you need to use it, e.g. when the compile times in big projects are really becoming slow due to much template usage.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot separate template class definition and implementation in different compilation units. In other words, `AdaBoost<T>` complete implementation should be linked in the same compilation unit that `main` (where it is used) is.

This is typically fixed by either `#including` the `.cpp` file at the end of your `.hpp` file (if you want to maintain them separate), or just using only the `.hpp` file implementing the whole class there.

Comment: Technically you can separate them if you explicitly instantiate all that's needed - not that this is used very often. Including `.cpp`s however could be a bit confusing, i'd rather use `.h`/`.hpp` for the implementation file as well.

Comment: Mmm..., but, @Georg, how are you going to instantiate explicitly what it is needed if part of the template is implemented into another separate file? You could instantiate `AdaBoost<double>` in the `.cpp` file, but this is even more confusing than including the `.cpp` :)

Comment: The OP already instantiates it in the `.cpp` :) It's not common, but can be important to cut down compile times in large projects.

Comment: As I commented to other post, this time I've worked around by using only .hpp (by copying all template functions from .cpp to .hpp file). Once I get enough reputation score I'll give a vote-up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems.

First, you use the unconventional technique of explicit instantiation in a CPP file. As others have pointed out, convention (but nothing more) requires that you put the implementation in the .H file to allow for generic instantiation. You don't have to do this, but if you did, the readfile() error would go away. (As an alternative, put your `AdaBoost<double>` instantiation *after* the definition of `AdaBoost::readfile`.)

Next, you have declared, but not defined, your constructor and destructor. If you wish to use the compiler-provided constructor and destructor you should delete the declarations. If you wish to use your own constructor and dstructor, you should define them.

Best practice is to get rid of AdaBoost.cpp, and modify AdaBoost.h to include the implementation inline in the header. (Note that this best practice is for templated classes; other advice may apply to non-templated classes.)

Comment: Thank you! As I commented to other posts, using only header works out. For constructor & deconstructor, you're right but it's just I've cut short too much from original files, in order to show them simple.